# Processing excel files with many data in PowerCenter

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I want to load an Excel file with many records, but it does not support me for the precision and I get an error on the monitor. I would like to know, how I can upload an excel file and support many data? using FTP and Data Transformation.

Comment: Could you pls share some sample data?  Can you use odbc?

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried so far, where is the issue, share the logs? Where are you trying to load excel data? It is possible in PowerCenter via ODBC to excel named area - have you hot that in place?